# Pushing an array into an object Javascipt

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a chart with chartJS.But my question is about basic question about javascript.

My html code is

```
<div class="static-spline-chart-1" data-points='[
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 3), y: 650 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 4), y: 700 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 5), y: 710 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 6), y: 658 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 7), y: 734 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 8), y: 963 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 9), y: 847 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 10), y: 853 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 11), y: 869 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 12), y: 943 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 13), y: 970 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 14), y: 869 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 15), y: 890 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 16), y: 930 }
                                ] '></div>
<div class="static-spline-chart-1" data-points='[
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 3), y: 650 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 4), y: 700 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 5), y: 710 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 6), y: 658 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 7), y: 734 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 8), y: 963 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 9), y: 847 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 10), y: 853 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 11), y: 869 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 12), y: 943 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 13), y: 970 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 14), y: 869 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 15), y: 890 },
                                    { x: new Date(2017, 0, 16), y: 930 }
                                ] '></div>
```

And Js code is:

```
    var StaticSplineChartOptions = {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    axisY: {
        lineThickness: 0,
        includeZero: false,
        gridThickness: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        lineThickness: 0,
        labelFontSize:0,
        margin:-20,
    },
    axisX: {
        labelFontSize:0,
        lineThickness: 0,
        includeZero: false,
        gridThickness: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        lineThickness: 0,
    },
    tickThickness: 0,

}
function RenderStaticSplineChart(className,options) {
    var charts = [];
    var chartClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = 0; i < chartClassElements.length; i++) {
        var dataPoints = chartClassElements[i].data('points');
        options.push({
            data: [{
                color: '#fff',
                type: "spline",
                markerSize: 0,
                dataPoints: dataPoints,
            }]
        });
        charts.push(new CanvasJS.Chart(chartClassElements[i], options));
        charts[i].render();
    }
}

RenderStaticSplineChart("static-spline-chart-1", StaticSplineChartOptions);
```

My objective is to make `StaticSplineChartOptions` like the following object

```
var StaticSplineChartOptions = {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    axisY: {
        lineThickness: 0,
        includeZero: false,
        gridThickness: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        lineThickness: 0,
        labelFontSize:0,
        margin:-20,
    },
    axisX: {
        labelFontSize:0,
        lineThickness: 0,
        includeZero: false,
        gridThickness: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        lineThickness: 0,
    },
    tickThickness: 0,
    data: [{
        color: '#fff',
        type: "spline",
        markerSize: 0,
        dataPoints: [
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 3), y: 650 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 4), y: 700 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 5), y: 710 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 6), y: 658 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 7), y: 734 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 8), y: 963 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 9), y: 847 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 10), y: 853 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 11), y: 869 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 12), y: 943 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 13), y: 970 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 14), y: 869 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 15), y: 890 },
            { x: new Date(2017, 0, 16), y: 930 }
        ] 
    }]
}
```

But i am getting such an error `jquery.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: chartClassElements[i].data is not a function` .
How i can get data attribute of that class in for loop? and how i get that above type of objects after getting that data?

Comment: You should use `chartClassElements[i].dataset.points` to access `data-attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

change 
`chartClassElements[i].data('points')`
to

```
chartClassElements[i].dataset.points
```

in the `RenderStaticSplineChart` function

Answer (score 0):

instead of chartClassElements[i].data('points')
try

```
chartClassElements[i].attr('data-points')
```

but you still have a problem with the rest of the code. the return of the above code is not in the array. its a simple text. you may put those data-points in html with some backendish language. try jsonify or serialize it. so after when you read it with js, by simply de serialize or parsing json, you can have the real array back